# Coloring a tikz cycle with a different color for each segment

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, diagrams, edge

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{asparagus}{rgb}{0.53, 0.66, 0.42}
\definecolor{bleudefrance}{rgb}{0.19, 0.55, 0.91}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{0.98, 0.6, 0.01}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections,bbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick,red] (30:1) node[above right,black!80] {$3$} -- (210:2);
    \draw[thick,orange!80]     (150:1) node[above left,black!80] {$2$} -- (330:2);
    \draw[thick,asparagus!80]     (270:1) node[below right,black!80] {$5$} -- (90:2);
    \draw      (90:2)  node[above right,black!80] {$1$} -- (210:2) node[below left,black!80] {$6$} -- (330:2) node[below right,black!80] {$7$} -- cycle;
    \draw[thick,bleudefrance!80]      (30:1cm) arc[start angle=30, end angle=270, radius=1cm];
    \fill (0:0)  node[above right,black!80] {$4$} circle(3pt)
          (30:1)  circle(3pt)
          (90:2)  circle(3pt)
          (150:1) circle(3pt)
          (210:2) circle(3pt)
          (270:1) circle(3pt)
          (330:2) circle(3pt);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Which gives me the following output:

[image]

Now, my question is: How would one color the cycle of lines that's full black with a different color in each segment (i.e., the edge that connects 6-2-1 should be with one color, the edge that connects 6-5-7 should have another color, and finally, the edge that connects 1-3-7 should also have a different color). The colors in case are not relevant.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You need to split up your fourth `\draw` in three paths, each with a different `draw=<color>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{asparagus}   {rgb}{0.53, 0.66, 0.42}
\definecolor{bleudefrance}{rgb}{0.19, 0.55, 0.91}
\definecolor{orange}      {rgb}{0.98, 0.6,  0.01}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick, red]          ( 30:1) node[above right,black!80] {$3$} -- (210:2);
\draw[thick, orange!80]    (150:1) node[above left, black!80] {$2$} -- (330:2);
\draw[thick, asparagus!80] (270:1) node[below right,black!80] {$5$} -- ( 90:2);
\draw (90:2) node[above right,black!80] {$1$}
  -- (210:2) node[below left, black!80] {$6$}
  -- (330:2) node[below right,black!80] {$7$} -- cycle;
\draw[thick, bleudefrance!80] (30:1) arc[start angle=30, end angle=270, radius=1];
\draw[thick, green]   (330:2) -- (90:2);  %<-- connects 1-3-7
\draw[thick, blue]    (210:2) -- (90:2);  %<-- connects 1-2-6
\draw[thick, magenta] (210:2) -- (330:2); %<-- connects 6-5-7
\fill[radius=3pt]
    (0:0) node[above right,black!80] {$4$}
            circle[]
    (30:1)  circle[]
    (90:2)  circle[]
    (150:1) circle[]
    (210:2) circle[]
    (270:1) circle[]
    (330:2) circle[];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]